# How to analyse a sentence and then list the positions in a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write a script that identifies individual words in a sentence, stores these in a list and replaces each word in the original sentence with the position of that word in the list.

For example, the sentence:

```
ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY
```

I would like the code to output:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,3,9,6,7,8,4,5
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
import csv
file = open("file.csv", "a+")
sentence =  ["I", "LIKE", "TO", "GO", "TO", "THE", "PARK"]
found = ""
for position, sentence in enumerate(sentence):
      found = found + str(position +1) + ","
new_record = found+","+sentence
file.write(str(found))
file.close()
```

It only outputs `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8..`

Comment: Please do not attempt to remove or vandalize your own question, as that isn't permitted. Answered questions are meant to stay as-is to be of use for future readers

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
sentence =  ["MY", "NAME", "IS", "JEFF", "AND", "JEFF", "LIKES", "CHEESE"]
found = ""
for word in sentence:
      found += str(sentence.index(word)+1) + ","
```

Output: `1,2,3,4,5,4,7,8,`

The last `,` should be chomped down with `found.rstrip(",")`

Comment: You could also use `found = []` and append each index to `found`. 
Then join each element using   `', '.join(found)`.

Comment: @Farhan.K, would doing so be more optimal? More Pythonic? It is a nice way to eliminate the `rstrip` though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the `csv` library as follows:

```
import csv

text = "ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY"
words = text.split()

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow([words.index(word)+1 for word in words])
```

This would give you `output.csv` containing the following:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,3,9,6,7,8,4,5
```

By using `with` it ensures that the file is automatically closed at the end, so there is no need to add `f_output.close()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> the_list='ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY'.split(" ")
>>> the_list
['ASK', 'NOT', 'WHAT', 'YOUR', 'COUNTRY', 'CAN', 'DO', 'FOR', 'YOU', 'ASK', 'WHAT', 'YOU', 'CAN', 'DO', 'FOR', 'YOUR', 'COUNTRY']
>>> [the_list.index(item)+1 for index,item in enumerate(the_list)]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 3, 9, 6, 7, 8, 4, 5]
```

Or as a function that takes a string (assuming same format of only words and spaces)

```
def indexer(the_string):
    return [the_string.split(" ").index(item)+1 for index,item in enumerate(the_string.split(" "))]
```

If you wanted a string output with just `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 3, 9, 6, 7, 8, 4, 5` (still assuming same format of input) you could just do a string representation of that list and replace `[` and `]` with an empty string.

```
>>>str([the_string.split(" ").index(item)+1 for index,item in enumerate(the_string.split(" "))]).replace("]","").replace("[","")
'1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 3, 9, 6, 7, 8, 4, 5'
```